# Angular: cant share data between components with guarded routes

Tags: angular, authentication, keycloak, share, guard

I'm trying to share data between siblings components that are guarded with a keycloak guard.

I can use router navigation extras state or a data service to share the data but only when the route is not guarded.

**Working code:**

```
  {
    path: 'path',
    component: ReceiverComponent
  },
```

**How i share:**

```
  // code from sender
  this.router.navigate(['path'], { state: { id: 1 } });

  or

  this.dataService.setData(data);

  // code from receiver (on constructor)
  this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.id

  or

  this.dataService.data?.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
```

If i activate the guard, both, states and data from service, are undefined on the receiver component, even if im logged and have full access:

**Dont work:**

```
  {
    path: 'path',
    component: ReceiverComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { roles: ['user'] },
  },
```

**My keycoak AuthGuard:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { KeycloakAuthGuard, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {
  constructor(
    protected readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService
  ) {
    super(router, keycloak);
  }

  public async isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      await this.keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url,
      });
    }

    const requiredRoles = route.data.roles;

    if (!(requiredRoles instanceof Array) || requiredRoles.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    if (requiredRoles.every((role) => this.roles.includes(role))) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['access-denied']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Keycloak is working fine denying/authorizing access to guarded routes.

It seems that state history is lost on guarded routes, like AUthGuard/Keycloak in the middle "consuming" the data shared, but I cant understand why would that affect the service layer.

Im new to angular so maybe Im doing something wrong, I dont know if is keycloak related, authguard configuration or something else. Thanks guys.

**What I want:**

Use authguard and be able to share data between non related components using states, service, etc.

**Versions:**

Angular: 11.2.13
Keycloak: 13.0.0
keycloak-angular: 8.2.0
keycloak-js: 13.0.0,

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain the sentence "I seems that state history is lost on guarded routes, but dont know why i cant access service data."? How are you trying to "access service data"? Can you show this code and debugging steps you've taken?

Comment: @AndrewAllen ty for your reply, I edit my post with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your guard is not responsible for the data you're trying to share, only for allowing/denying access to the route. Usually, for these cases you just put the data you're trying to share on a service. You'll be able to access that data from the component that needs it regardless of whether you're logged in or not (this is just some state on the client side, not the same as asking some authenticated endpoint for data).

On the other hand, if you just want to pass some **static** data to a specific route, you can do so via that route's `data` object and then access it on your component via ActivatedRoute. Something like this:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(myData => console.log(myData));
}
```

Nevertheless, there are some other ways to pass some data from one page to another, like using query parameters, which may also help you with what you're trying to achieve. Check this example from the [Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments).

Comment: ty, I dont remember if I tried with ActivatedRoute (I tried a lot of things, I'll check again) and I read that guide too. About queryparams for some cases with complex data they are not very helpful. What i think is odd is that if I remove the AuthGuard everything works as supose to do.